# Prevent subdirectory from being a part of the link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webaddress

I am currently refactoring my website and I noticed that my nested structure shows up like I'm browsing through `File Explorer`. I couldn't find anything on the web about preventing that from showing up that way.

I like to ensure my project is nice and organized and this results in pages that are sometimes up to 5 layers deep (basic example):

```
mywebsitedotcom/gaming/2d/arcade/pong.aspx
```

I would prefer this to look like:

```
mywebsitedotcom/gaming/pong.aspx
```

How do I ensure the web address doesn't display part of my organizational structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something called **UrlMapping**.

It is an element that goes in your web.config and it will similar to this:

```
<system.web>

<urlMappings enabled="true">

    <add url="~/gaming/2d/arcade/pong.aspx"
        mappedUrl="~/gaming/pong.aspx"/>

    <add url="~/anotherurl/another.aspx"
        mappedUrl="~/otherurl/otherpage.aspx"/>

</urlMappings>
```